# OGF of the numerator

Tags: generating-functions

I am interested in finding the ordinary generating function of the numerator in the sum

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{4m + 3}}$$

I have tried this problem for quite considerable amount of time. After spending some time I was able to figure out that when $m = 0$ then the numerator is $\pi^3$, whereas when $m = 1$ then the numerator turns out to be $13\pi^7$. This seems quite interesting. There's definitely some pattern going on here. However I'm not able to figure it out.

I really don't care much about the denominator since it seems to grow quite large very quickly. I am only interested in the numerator of the infinite series.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you forgot the $\pi$'s. For $m=0$, the numerator is $\pi^3$, for $m=1$ it is $13 \pi^7$

Comment: Oh Yeah, Thanks. I've now corrected it.